# Over current Protection for Ne555 circuit?

Tags: circuit-protection, 555

I made simple frequency generator circuit with Ne555 but almost in every circuit Ne555 IC burns after few use. Ne555 starting to heat up then outputs weird signals , if I don't stop the supply Ne555 literally burns to crisp .

I'm thinking the reason is over current but I always add minimum 1k ohm resistor to output and supply voltage is 12v (with 10A fuse)

My first question is where the over current happens and second question is how can I prevent it ? ( Prevention and fail-safe (fuse or extra resistor))

D1 is schottky diode (1n5819) Speaker is 1W 8ohm , I tried to remove L1 and C3 , change C2 with 100nF capacitor , changed R3 location between L1 and LS1

Last picture is my last circuit before Ne555 start to heat up (C2 is 100nF picture wrong)

## I found the problem L1 and C3 caused short circuit with 0.3 ohm resistance but can anyone suggest general over current protection for this circuit ?

[image: First Circuit]
[image: Las Circuit]

Comment: Nothing in this diagram would explain it. You must have a wiring error in your actual implementation. Can you show us a picture of it?

Comment: The 10A fuse is pretty much useless

Comment: How are you connecting the power supply? The quickest way of toasting a 555 is to reverse the polarity of the supply.

Comment: Well to be honest I don't know when the error happened , only thing I know somehow output pin current rise too much and it burned the Ne555 . I'm writing the last circuit diagrams in few minutes

Comment: I'm pretty sure I connected supply correctly , positive and negative voltage in different side rail so you can't mix it

Comment: Show your **whole** circuit, including the inductor you mentioned.  The circuit you've shown is **not** your real circuit since it doesn't have the inductor, the big capacitor, or the speaker you mentioned.

Comment: I made several circuits and I don't know when it started to burn but I will add all of them

Comment: I added new circuits but my main question is how can I protect my circuit like fuse or extra resistor ? (Mistakes will happen)

Comment: C3 should be in series with the speaker - where L1 is - and delete L1.  470 uF in parallel with the speaker willl KILL any audio.

Comment: What is the purpose of L1?

Comment: @Mordecai I'm curious about the parasitic capacitance across your diode. It's possible that the DIS pin is having to sink (for a very small period of time) a large current. Can you try simply removing that diode (I know it won't behave the same, but it should still do something) and see if your devices still "burn to a crisp?" I'm assuming you got things wired as stated, for now, and just looking for anything at all that might lead to either high voltages or excessive currents and the diode parasitic capacitance (few hundred pF?) is all I can see given what you have shown.

Comment: L1 trying to convert square signal to sinus wave but I think I misunderstood the circuit. In my calculations 
 resonance supposed to do the trick but it's creating short circuit  http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Sine-wave-generator-circuit-with-a-555-timer.php

Comment: If I add 50-100 ohm resistor to supply it should prevent over current ? Output's maximum current is 200mA so it can't draw more than because of resistor ?